# django - display the units of the selected item

Tags: django, django-forms

Items model has units which is foreign to Units model. Now when we select the item in stock form, how to display the units of the selected item?

## models.py

```
class Units(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    
class Items(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    units = models.ForeignKey(Units, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name='units_items')
    
class Stock(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Items, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False, blank=False, related_name='item_stock')
    - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
    - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
```

## forms.py:

```
class StockForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Stock
        fields = ['item']
```

## template:

```
<div class="col-md-4 pl-0">
    {{ formsingle.item|as_crispy_field }}
</div>

<div class="col-md-1 p-0">
    <span></span> //here how to show related units when any item is selected
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the template,

```
{{ selected_item.units.name }}
```

If you want this to happen without a round-trip to the server (form submit) you will with have to use JavaScript and AJAX to retrieve the appropriate units whenever a selection is made, or incorporate the units in the textual choices which comprise the modelchoice field.

See [ModelchoiceField iterator documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField.iterator)

If doing it this way you should also use a queryset that performs a select_related on units, so you don't cause a Database query for every time you refer to `item.units`